# Failure with "<file.ext> is not a instance of ModelObject." on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins, and while trying to run my project on jenkins I have the error as  is not a instance of ModelObject.

I don't know what it means, and what is the fix for this.

Comment: This question is not clear enough, can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Hey Raj welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is missing some of the key aspect of a  question. Please provide a code that tried to solve your problem. In your case please provide code or code snippet that is causing this exception. And please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)